# Error receiving broadcast Intent Bluetooth adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I'm having a problem passing an arrayList using an Intent. When the search finishes,and runs ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED, the application just stop running.

**DesafioActivity:(sender)**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                mProgressDlg.show();
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                mProgressDlg.dismiss();

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(DesafioActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

                newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

                startActivity(newIntent);
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                mDeviceList.add(device);

                showToast("Dispositivo Encontrado " + device.getName());
            }
        }
    };
```

**DevicesListActivity;(receiver)**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_devices);

    mDeviceList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

    mAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(this);

    mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
    mAdapter.setListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
            BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);

            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                unpairDevice(device);
            } else {
                showToast("Pairing...");

                pairDevice(device);
            }
        }
    });
```

**LogCat:**

```
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): Process: com.AMOV.mr.fit, PID: 14779
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED flg=0x10 } in com.AMOV.mr.fit.DesafioActivity$1@4198efa8
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:785)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.AMOV.mr.fit/com.AMOV.mr.fit.DeviceListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.AMOV.mr.fit.DesafioActivity$1.onReceive(DesafioActivity.java:149)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:775)
12-31 17:33:04.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    ... 9 more
12-31 17:33:06.855: I/Process(14779): Sending signal. PID: 14779 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Entire logcat please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeviceListActivity isn't declared in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i just saw it now also... I'm sorry, but i'm starting now :)
Thank's btw!

Comment: Glad it worked, if it resolve your problem don't forget to close the question.